# Splitting and replacing strings in a 2D list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a set of data as shown below:

```
[['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01','A','<>TG:MIN MAX W1 GRN RED'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01','B','MIN MAX'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07','A','<i>TG:MAX MIN W2'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07','C','MAX RED GRN'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:20','A','MIN MAX RED'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:01:00','A','<i>TG:MAX MIN RED GRN']]
```

As shown in the 3 value of the line, it may or maynot include "<>TG". I would like to detect for

```
"<i>"
```

and split it out of the string then add it to become the 4th column

The desired output will be

```
[['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01', 'A', '<>TG:MIN MAX W1 GRN RED'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01', 'B', 'MIN MAX'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07', 'A', 'TG:MAX MIN W2', '<i>'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07', 'C', 'MAX RED GRN'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:20', 'A', 'MIN MAX RED'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:01:00', 'A', 'TG:MAX MIN RED GRN', '<i>']]
```

Please Advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? Just iterate over the sublists and update inplace.

```
for l in lst:
    if '<i>TG' in l[-1]:
        l[-1] = l[-1].replace('<i>', '')
        l.append('<i>')       

print(lst)
```

```
[['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01', 'A', '<>TG:MIN MAX W1 GRN RED'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01', 'B', 'MIN MAX'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07', 'A', 'TG:MAX MIN W2', '<i>'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07', 'C', 'MAX RED GRN'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:20', 'A', 'MIN MAX RED'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:01:00', 'A', 'TG:MAX MIN RED GRN', '<i>']]
```

If you want to check for the token at the start of the string, change

```
if '<i>TG' in l[-1]
```

to

```
if l[-1].startswith('<i>TG')
```

(You don't need regex.)

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter, use `list comprehension`:

```
print([[y if x!=2 else y.replace('<i>','') for x,y in enumerate(i)]+['<i>'] if '<i>' in i[-1] else i for i in lst])
```

Or if want in the beginning:

```
print([[y if x!=2 else y.lstrip('<i>') for x,y in enumerate(i)]+['<i>'] if i[-1].startswith('<i>') else i for i in lst])\
```

Both output:

```
[['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01', 'A', '<>TG:MIN MAX W1 GRN RED'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01', 'B', 'MIN MAX'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07', 'A', 'TG:MAX MIN W2', '<i>'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07', 'C', 'MAX RED GRN'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:20', 'A', 'MIN MAX RED'],
 ['05-Feb-2001 12:01:00', 'A', 'TG:MAX MIN RED GRN', '<i>']]
```

Comment: Simple maybe, but why recreate the entire list when modifying a single column?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to check one entry in the data list of lists then `map` apply it to the list:

```
data = [['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01','A','<>TG:MIN MAX W1 GRN RED'],
        ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01','B','MIN MAX'],
        ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07','A','<i>TG:MAX MIN W2'],
        ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07','C','MAX RED GRN'],
        ['05-Feb-2001 12:00:20','A','MIN MAX RED'],
        ['05-Feb-2001 12:01:00','A','<i>TG:MAX MIN RED GRN']]

def separate(entry, separator='<i>', position=2):
    return [
        el.replace(separator, '') if idx==position else el for idx, el in enumerate(entry)] + (
            [] if not separator in entry[position] 
            else [separator]
        )

from itertools import repeat
map(separate, data, repeat('<i>'), repeat(2))

Out[26]: 
[['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01', 'A', '<>TG:MIN MAX W1 GRN RED'],
['05-Feb-2001 12:00:01', 'B', 'MIN MAX'],
['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07', 'A', 'TG:MAX MIN W2', '<i>'],
['05-Feb-2001 12:00:07', 'C', 'MAX RED GRN'],
['05-Feb-2001 12:00:20', 'A', 'MIN MAX RED'],
['05-Feb-2001 12:01:00', 'A', 'TG:MAX MIN RED GRN', '<i>']]
```

Note: If you are using python 2.x, then `repeat` need the additional argument `times=len(data)`.